Как настроить порядок столбцов в таблице в pandas python?
Есть таблица в excel:



Id
BSS
RP
BS_name
Project
BSC
TG
CELL
BS_number
RSITE
SW
Cell_ID
LAC
bsic
RBL2_1
RBL2_2
OETM_1
OETM_2
Reg




71274
OK
OK
test0466-B
-
VLD321
0
test04661
2628
test0466
-
04661
52401
30
-
-
-
-
test


71275
OK
OK
test0466-B
-
VLD321
0
test04662
2628
test0466
-
04661
52401
30
-
-
-
-
test


71276

OK
test0173-B-II
-


test01731
0173


1731

31
-
-
-
-
test


71277

OK
test0173-B-II
-


test01732
0173


1731

31
-
-
-
-
test


71278

OK
test0173-B-II
-


test01733
0173


1731

31
-
-
-
-
test


71279
OK
OK
test0466-B
-
VLD321
0
test04664
2628
test0466
-
04661
52401
30
-
-
-
-
test


71281
OK
OK
test0466-B
-
VLD321
0
test04665
2628
test0466
-
04661
52401
30
-
-
-
-
test



Мой код выводит таблицу с нужными мне для задачи столбцами:




BSS
Reg
BS_name
BSC
TG
CELL
RSITE
SW
LAC
RBL2_1
RBL2_2
OETM_1
OETM_2




25
NaN
test
test0173-B-II
NaN
NaN
test01731
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN


26
NaN
test
test0173-B-II
NaN
NaN
test01732
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN


27
NaN
test
test0173-B-II
NaN
NaN
test01733
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN



Но как мне реализовать таблицу со столбцами в следующем порядке и желательно без столбца BSS:



Reg
BS_name
BSC
TG
RSITE
SW
LAC
RBL2_1
RBL2_2
OETM_1
OETM_2
CELL




test
test0173-B-II
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
test01731


test
test0173-B-II
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
test01732


test
test0173-B-II
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
test01733



Вот мой код:
import pandas as pd
#ces = pd.read_excel('Table\ Integrated\ Sites.xlsx')
cols = [2, 6, 8, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 66, 67, 68, 69]
#print(ces.head())
ces = pd.read_excel('Table Integrated Sites.xlsx', skiprows=1, usecols=cols)
#print(ces)
table1 = ces[ces['BSS'].isna()]
print(table1)
filtercols = table1.reindex(columns=[0, 2, 1])
#print(filtercols)

в filtercols я пытался поменять местами столбец - не помогло.

filtercols = table1[['Reg', 'BS_name', 'BSC', 'TG', 'RSITE', 'SW', 'LAC', 'RBL2_1', 'RBL2_2', 'OETM_1', 'OETM_2', 'CELL']]
